# Is there a way to bulk delete unused jenkins jobs? (not run in the last 6 months)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have a Jenkins instance with multiple teams using it. It gets cluttered frequently and people don't delete their test jobs after testing. Is there a way to delete unused jobs (not run in the last 6 months) including their workspace?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What do you have so far? What did you try? Just searching S/O gives multiple answers to do exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Groovy script for this. Comment out the delete part and test it before using just to make sure it's what you need :)

```
def deleteBefore = "2022/07/01"

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
      def jobName = jobitem.getFullName()
  
      def deleteBeforeTime = new Date(deleteBefore).getTime()

      def build = jobitem.getLastBuild() 
  
    if(build == null || build.getTimeInMillis() <= deleteBeforeTime){ // If no builds, build is null
        
      println build == null ? "Job " + jobName + " has never run, deleting the Job" : "Job " + jobName + " last ran on (" + build.getTime() + ") hence deleting"
      jobitem.delete()
        
    }    
}
```

Comment: From a User Experience perspective, it would probably be more convenient to disable the job, delete the workspace and delete all but the last successful build (and optionally delete ArchivedArtifacts for last build if space is needed). The job config itself takes up  little space. Re-enabling if needed is far more convenient than re-creating, plus you have the lat build # to resume from and last log to refer to. You can then delete the jobs if still disabled after a longer period if so choose. /1

Comment: /2 Of course, if you have the [Job Config History plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jobConfigHistory/) installed, you can resurrect deleted jobs (but not run histories), but that also means the config histories remain after job deletion and consume some space.